navigator.clipboard.writeText not working on mobile
I have no idea why this doesn't work:
js:
const copybutton = document.getElementById('copy');

copybutton.addEventListener('click', function(){

   copybutton.innerHTML = "[<i>email copied to clipboard</i>]";  
   navigator.clipboard.writeText("email@gmail.com");

}
)

html:
<button id="copy"> send a message</button>
All I managed to find is that it needs to be triggered by an event listener, which it definitely is. Works well on mobile. On mobile chrome it worked as an inline snippet but not when I made it into an event listener in a separate doc. Is the support bad for it?
(project uses JQuery as well, if that helps.)

To eliminate the obvious, is the external script loaded in the head of your page or at the bottom, towards the end of the body tag? You could be dealing with a simple timing issue

It's 2024; I find it very difficult to think of a legitimate (and non-archeological) reason to use jQuery in a project...

bottom of the page! as stated, it works fine on desktop. one hypothesis, both mobile devices I tested this with are quite old and maybe don't have the latest versions of browsers. Is there an old-school way of doing it that I can try if clipboard API fails?

@Dai I just want draggable divs and didn't want to write it myself. Does it slow down page load by a lot?

Two things to note here, not directly related to the question. writeText() returns a Promise which should be awaited or then()ed. You should also update the text in the div only when that Promise successfully resolved. To make sure you also support older browsers (which you seem to be concerned with) you can use a progressive enhancement like this one here proposed by Google or the web.dev authors.

As for the question, you could also have a permission issue (although copy to clipboard should be automatically granted for the active tab). Be sure to checkout this blog post on web.dev for details on that. There are some gotchas here e.g. the Clipboard API only works with HTTPS, so be sure to check the blog post out.

@Mushroomator thank you! It seems to have been a case of old browser simply.
